# Embedding DT package generated table in HTML

Tags: r, dt

I am trying to use DT as a part of HTML report. So far, I have been using xtable and R2HTML R package. I am also new to web technologies as well.

The problem is, unlike xtable, the DT package creates the whole HTML code, and it opens browser automatically. There is an option "escape = FALSE", but I cannot find any other way to embed DT object into HTML.

I hope to know how I can embedded those created HTML by DT into other HTML. It seems a very basic technology in HTML developers, but for me it is very hard to find a way to doing this.

In case of using xtable and R2HTML, the code to generate new HTML is like belows:

```
html.handle <- HTMLInitFile(outdir=".", filename="name", Title="test")
HTML(xtable(iris), file = html.handle)
HTML('<b>we can also add other HTML code in this html. I hope to do the same by using DT, but I don't know how to do this</b>', file = html.handle)
```

However, in case of DT, I have no idea how I can embed the created HTML table into this html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you doing this in a `rmarkdown` document?

Comment: No, I just did it by normal R script code.

Comment: Why do you want to use DT? Just try using rmarkdown which is an awesome tool. Have a look at `knitr::kable` for HTML Table: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/knitr/docs/kable

Comment: It gives a better way of customizing tables than xtable, and that's the only reason. Thank you for the recommendation, I will check knitr.